# Are AJAX requests to servers with TLS 1.0 blocked in android 10?

Tags: android, ajax, ssl

I have just started work on a legacy project, and API calls are not working to a rails backend with TLS 1.0 on new versions of Android. Androids running android 9 or lower seem unaffected. Is this because of the old TLS version?

Answer (score 0):

As the Android 10 document says it uses TLS 1.3 by default you should use the latest TLS version for enhanced security.
[Android 10 Highlights](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights#security)